# Odoo10 Working setup now failing with ImportError: No module named conf

Tags: odoo-10

*Working setup failing with ImportError: No module named conf*

I stopped test setup on localhost with ^c to check logs

on restart I am getting error

```
C:\Odoo 10.0\server>odoo-bin -d todo -i todo_app --test-enable --dev=all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "odoo-bin", line 2, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 2203, in declare_namespace

  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 2219, in declare_namespace

  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 2186, in _handle_ns

  File "pkgutil.pyc", line 246, in load_module
    argument should be the name of a package, in standard module format
  File "C:\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    import conf
ImportError: No module named conf
```

TEST - Create folder conf with **init**.py from github

RESULT

```
C:\Odoo 10.0\server>odoo-bin -d todo -i todo_app --test-enable --dev=all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "odoo-bin", line 2, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 2203, in declare_namespace

  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 2219, in declare_namespace

  File "pkg_resources\__init__.pyc", line 2186, in _handle_ns

  File "pkgutil.pyc", line 246, in load_module
    argument should be the name of a package, in standard module format
  File "C:\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    import conf
  File "C:\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\conf\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import deprecation
ImportError: No module named deprecation
```

CONCLUSION - Something happened to module conf - but I do not know what as I have made no such changes - **John**

Answer (score 5):

I think you are using python 3.x .
this problem happened to me on linux but after using python 2.7.x it started as normal.